# javascript window.location iframe, make parent window go to location

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know on the same page frame or parent I can make either go to something via `window.location` however is there a means of checking to see if I am in the iframe and if so make the top (parent window) location go somewhere?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

This is a simple code to check if your page is loaded in iframe:

```
if (window.location != window.parent.location)
    window.parent.location = "http://someurl";
```

Comment: tell me why is it always the simple things that evade me the most.. ay ya.. thank you.. :-)

Comment: Well, you can thank me by upvoting and accepting my answer :)